# Xml Xpath Expression for Nested XML

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

I have a XML

```
<font-text content-format="howdy" data-type="text">
<Index>1</Index>
<Root>1</Root>
<Result>302</Result>
</font-text>
```

What would be the Xpath expression for the above XMS if I want to take out "Index","Root" & "Result" values in the format "302-01-01"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath `string-join()` and `format-number()` functions to the rescue.

`format-number()` function exists in XSLT 2.0

It was moved from XSLT 3.0 to XPath 3.0

> XPath 3.0

```
string-join((/font-text/Result/text(), format-number(/font-text/Root/text(),'00'), format-number(/font-text/Index/text(),'00')), "-")
```

> XPath 2.0

```
string-join((/font-text/Result/text()
, substring(concat("00", /font-text/Root/text()), string-length(concat("00",/font-text/Root/text())) - 1)
, substring(concat("00", /font-text/Index/text()), string-length(concat("00",/font-text/Index/text())) - 1))
, "-")
```

> XPath 1.0

```
concat(/font-text/Result/text()
, "-"
, substring(concat("00", /font-text/Root/text()), string-length(concat("00",/font-text/Root/text())) - 1)
, "-"
, substring(concat("00", /font-text/Index/text()), string-length(concat("00",/font-text/Index/text())) - 1)
)
```

Comment: Using "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" to compile...Its saying could not find function:string-join

Comment: Check it out here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-string-join

Comment: Using Java xml "xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(node);".Not working here

Comment: I showed three different solutions by using different versions of  XPath. Did you try all of them?

Comment: My bad it worked...thanks for your help much appreciated